# Javascript for sliding down a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Guys I have this html with the following code.It has 2 forms.formA and form B.I have icluded a java script also.I want to make the formB slide down,when I click the link "Internet banking" above form A and when i click on "card payment" vice versa.

```
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Payment Page</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.creditCardValidator.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
```

this is the javascript I added.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#formA").click(function(){
        $("#internet").slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });
    </script>
    <div class="demo">

        <form id="formA">

    <a href="#formA" class="tabHeader">Card Payment</a>
    <a href="#formB" class="tabHeader">Internet banking</a>

     <h2>Card Payment</h2>

            <input type='hidden' id='ccType' name='ccType' />
            <ul class="cards">
                <li class="visa">Visa</li>
                <li class="visa_electron">Visa Electron</li>
                <li class="mastercard">MasterCard</li>
                <li class="maestro">Maestro</li>
            </ul>
            <label for="card_number">Card number</label>
            <input type="text" name="card_number" id="card_number">
            <div class="vertical">
                <label for="expiry_date">Expiry date <small>mm/yy</small>

                </label>
                <input type="text" name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date" maxlength="5">
                <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
                <input type="text" name="cvv" id="cvv" maxlength="3">
            </div>
            <div class="vertical maestro">
                <label for="issue_date">Issue date <small>mm/yy</small>

                </label>
                <input type="text" name="issue_date" id="issue_date" maxlength="5"> <span class="or">or</span>

                <label for="issue_number">Issue number</label>
                <input type="text" name="issue_number" id="issue_number" maxlength="2">
            </div>
            <label for="name_on_card">Name On card</label>
            <input type="text" name="name_on_card" id="name_on_card">
            <input type="submit" value="Pay Now !">
        </form>
        <form id="formB">
    <div id="internet">     
    <a href="#formA" class="tabHeader">Card Payment</a>
    <a href="#formB" class="tabHeader">Internet banking</a>

     <h2>Internet Banking</h2>

        <ul class="cards">
                <li class="visa">Visa</li>
                <li class="visa_electron">Visa Electron</li>
                <li class="mastercard">MasterCard</li>
                <li class="maestro">Maestro</li>
            </ul>

        </form>
    </div>

    </body>
```

here is the @http://jsfiddle.net/pz83w/5/   demo.Im new to java script,so this is my experiment.Couldsomeone figure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your function in the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".tabHeader").click(function(){
  $(".form").each(function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
          $(this).slideUp(400).removeClass('show');
      } else {
          $(this).delay(400).addClass('show').slideDown();
      }
  });
  });
});
```

Here is working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pz83w/7/

Remember, since you have two buttons, it's better to use class selector than to use id, same with your forms. That you can add a blank class (like 'show' in the example) to selected item and animate it the way you want.

Fiddle is updated, check HTML section, since I added classes to your forms.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, you need to check HTLM section of it, since I added classes to your forms and that is what makes it work.

Comment: Thank you so.Helped a lot :)